# Can I "naïvely" claim that (complex) Taylor series are all analytic because...

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Can I "naïvely" claim that (complex) Taylor series are all analytic because each one of their terms is clearly entire?

The reason for my hesitation is because there are infinitely many terms involved, so it's not clear to me why such a justification must necessarily hold.

Sure, we're handling series over their convergence discs, but why does that matter?

Comment: Define "analytic"

Comment: @reuns A function is analytic if it's differentiable on its domain that happens to be a region, i.e. its domain is an open, connected subset of C.

Comment: You have a problem of definitions. Start with complex differentiable at a point, then holomorphic : complex differentiable at every point of an open set of $\mathbb{C}$, analytic : represented by a power series in some neighborhood of every point in the open set. That analytic implies holomorphic is not hard, it relies on the series of termwise derivative being locally convergent. That holomorphic implies analytic is the main result of Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: @reuns We are not using the same terminology, so let me rephrase.  "Why can I claim that any Taylor series is differentiable on its domain (i.e. on the set on which it converges)?  Is the naïve observation that everyone one of the terms of the series is differentiable over C enough?  Even though there are infinitely many terms?  Why?

Comment: The terminology I mentioned is the one you need to use to make everything clear. If $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ converges for $|z| < r$ then $|a_n| (r-\epsilon)^n <  C_\epsilon $ so $g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n z^{n-1}$ converges for $|z| < r-\epsilon$ whence for $|z| < r$. That $g(z) = f'(z)$ is then a matter of integrating $g$ (as $\int_0^z g(s)ds = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n \int_0^z s^{n-1}ds$ by uniform convergence), or finding a bound for $|\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}-g(z)|$ in term of $ h \sup_{|s| \le |z|} |g'(s)|$

Comment: @reuns Thanks.  This also confirms my suspicion that my argument was a bit inadequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your definitions wrong, and the comments seem to suggest this as well.

A function $f$ defined on an open subset $\mathrm{O}$ of the normed vector space $\mathbf{F}^p$ (where $\mathbf{F}$ is either the real or complex field) with values in *any* normed vector space $\mathrm{X}$ (over the same field $\mathbf{F}$) is *analytic* if, for whatever point $o \in \mathrm{O},$ there exists a neighbourhood of $o$ and a family of vectors $(c_\nu)_{\nu \in \mathbf{Z}_+^p}$ such that the family $(c_\nu (z-o)^\nu)$ is absolutely summable and its sum coincides with $f(z)$ ($z$ belonging to the neighbourhood mentioned), where for any vector $t = (t_1, \ldots, t_p) \in \mathbf{F}^p$ we write $t^\nu = t_1^{\nu_1} \cdots t_p^{\nu_p} \in \mathbf{F},$ a scalar.

In the particular case in which $\mathbf{F} = \mathbf{C}$ and $\mathrm{X} = \mathbf{C}^q$ we have the celebrated theorem of Hartog-Goursat-Cauchy which says that a function $f$ is analytic on an open set if and only if it has partial derivatives.

To boil it down to $p = q = 1,$ we have that a complex-valued function  defined on an open subset of the complex plane is analytic if and only if it is differentiable (or as is sometimes say: "holomorphic").

To relate this to your question, if you give any power series $(a_n z^n)_{n \in \mathbf{Z}_+}$ in one complex variable, then it will define an analytic function wherever the series converges. If the series converges on an open set (which can be proven to be necessarily some disc) around zero and $f$ is the function so defined, then the Taylor's coefficients of $f$ are $a_n$ because $f^{(n)}(0)=n!a_n$ from basic differentiation of absolutely sure power series.

Comment: You should stop saying I have my definitions wrong :-)  I don't.  Different textbooks can sometimes use different definitions. Mine appears to use a different one than yours, that's all.  Here's my textbook's definition: https://i.imgur.com/KH53KOz.png

Comment: In fact, your definition is a much general version of mine. Thanks for the additional clarification.

Comment: @Stephen I agree that, as stated in my answer, analyticity and existence of partial derivatives agree when we are dealing with finite dimensional complex vector spaces. Although, they are different concepts. Maybe it's not “wrong” but still....

Comment: @stephen I hope the ammended answer is what you were looking for